# When importing/creating branch from git project, I get multiple source folders

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I have a Maven project that I imported from Git, and when I either checkout into a local branch or import the project I get a layout that looks like this:

[image]

In the project setup on file/github it looks correct. The hierarchy is

```
src
    --->main
        --->resources
        --->java
    --->test
```

It seems likes it creating multiple src folders but I wasn't sure how to change that in the build path/ why its doing this.

I should also mention the original src folder contains duplicates of the other src folders, but pads the packages with main.java.

For reference I'm using Eclipse Neon EE.

Comment: _"it [is] creating multiple src folders "_ -- The repetition of `src/` is normal in the flat view, that is the same `src` folder on each line.  Is that what you're referring to?  Look at the files in a file manager (Windows Explorer or equivalent on Linux) and you will not find a duplicate `src` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project Explorer view, switch to a [hierarchical presentation](http://blog.jabby-techs.fr/2015/05/19/Eclipse-Mars-episode-1-Vue-hierarchique-des-projets.html):

[image: http://tools.jboss.org/blog/images/nested_projects_m5.png]

<sup>(Image from "[JBoss Tools Alpha1 for Eclipse Mars](http://tools.jboss.org/blog/2015-02-23-alpha1-for-mars.html)" article from [Max Rydahl Andersen](https://twitter.com/maxandersen))</sup>

You should then see only one `src`.

Comment: So I don't have a drop down for projects presentation. The first item on the menu is Top Level Elements. And then everything following that.

Comment: @rinaldo13531 Strange: are you in the "project explorer" view?

Comment: Ohhhh I got switched to package explorer. Thankss for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try to run the "mvn eclipse:eclipse" command in maven to clean/build the code.